# Change thread permissions in Windows using C

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, security, permissions

I have a server application, that uses multi client method. When it detect a new request, makes a new socket for new client first. Then makes a new **thread** for it and new thread will do whatever it should.
When I make a new thread for my client, **it is unsafe to execute it as an administrator** (my application is running as an administrator itself). I want to change it's permissions to **Users group** permissions. I mean **the therad should be execute as a limited user, not an administrator.**
My platform is **Microsoft Windows**, and my programming language is **C**. How can I do that? I searched the internet, but I found nothing.
Could you please send me a sample program here?

Comment: Look up "impersonation".

Comment: It depends what you mean.  A thread can impersonate another security context, but there is no "trapdoor" support; if the thread is running untrusted code, there's no way to prevent the code from reverting to full privilege.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  All the threads within a process run as the same user with the same elevation level.

The only way to do what you're asking is to start a new process rather than a new thread.  This article might be helpful: [Running as Limited User - the Easy Way](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2006/03/02/running-as-limited-user-the-easy-way.aspx).

Comment: We have "setuid()" function that does the same work in Linux. When you create a thread you can change its permission in the thread itself. I mean, at first line of the function that thread executes, you can change its permission, and then you can do whatever you want. Does any function exists in windows like that?

Comment: Do you mean that when I set user ID in a thread, whole process get the same user ID?

Comment: yes. User/Permission stuff is per process, not per thread. Threads share the same address space, so it would not make sense to allow them to have different permissions, since they could just manipulate the execution of other threads.

Comment: I don't think so. Because I have a code, that I wrote it myself. and it works. Every thread in my code have its permissions itself that is different from other threads. I can post it here if you want.